# How to get the ParseTree even when there is a syntax error in the code in nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn, parse-tree

```
String parseTree = parse(code, "nashorn", true);
```

The above code is what i use to get the parse tree from the code.
if I pass the below code (Syntactically correct code)

```
String code = "function a (){\n" +
                "            var  a = 10;\n" +
                "            if(a>20){\n" +
                "                a=a+1;\n" +
                "            }else{\n" +
                "                a=a-1;\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        }";
```

It gives me

```
{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":1,"column":0},"end":{"line":1,"column":0}},"type":"Program","body":[{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":1,"column":13},"end":{"line":1,"column":13}},"type":"FunctionDeclaration","id":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":1,"column":9},"end":{"line":1,"column":10}},"type":"Identifier","name":"a"},"params":[],"defaults":[],"rest":null,"body":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":1,"column":13},"end":{"line":7,"column":13}},"type":"BlockStatement","body":[{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":2,"column":12},"end":{"line":2,"column":23}},"type":"VariableDeclaration","declarations":[{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":2,"column":17},"end":{"line":2,"column":18}},"type":"VariableDeclarator","id":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":2,"column":17},"end":{"line":2,"column":18}},"type":"Identifier","name":"a"},"init":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":2,"column":21},"end":{"line":2,"column":23}},"type":"Literal","value":10}}]},{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":3,"column":12},"end":{"line":7,"column":13}},"type":"IfStatement","test":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":3,"column":15},"end":{"line":3,"column":19}},"type":"BinaryExpression","operator":">","left":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":3,"column":15},"end":{"line":3,"column":16}},"type":"Identifier","name":"a"},"right":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":3,"column":17},"end":{"line":3,"column":19}},"type":"Literal","value":20}},"consequent":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":3,"column":20},"end":{"line":5,"column":13}},"type":"BlockStatement","body":[{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":4,"column":16},"end":{"line":4,"column":21}},"type":"ExpressionStatement","expression":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":4,"column":16},"end":{"line":4,"column":21}},"type":"AssignmentExpression","operator":"=","left":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":4,"column":16},"end":{"line":4,"column":17}},"type":"Identifier","name":"a"},"right":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":4,"column":18},"end":{"line":4,"column":21}},"type":"BinaryExpression","operator":"+","left":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":4,"column":18},"end":{"line":4,"column":19}},"type":"Identifier","name":"a"},"right":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":4,"column":20},"end":{"line":4,"column":21}},"type":"Literal","value":1}}}}]},"alternate":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":5,"column":17},"end":{"line":7,"column":13}},"type":"BlockStatement","body":[{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":6,"column":16},"end":{"line":6,"column":21}},"type":"ExpressionStatement","expression":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":6,"column":16},"end":{"line":6,"column":21}},"type":"AssignmentExpression","operator":"=","left":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":6,"column":16},"end":{"line":6,"column":17}},"type":"Identifier","name":"a"},"right":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":6,"column":18},"end":{"line":6,"column":21}},"type":"BinaryExpression","operator":"-","left":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":6,"column":18},"end":{"line":6,"column":19}},"type":"Identifier","name":"a"},"right":{"loc":{"source":"nashorn","start":{"line":6,"column":20},"end":{"line":6,"column":21}},"type":"Literal","value":1}}}}]}}]},"generator":false,"expression":false}]}
```

But If There is a Syntax error in the code as a example if i remove the { near the else

```
     String a = "function a (){\n" +
                "            var  a = 10;\n" +
                "            if(a>20){\n" +
                "                a=a+1;\n" +
                "            else{\n" +
                "                a=a-1;\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        }";
```

it gives me

```
ECMAScript Exception: SyntaxError: nashorn:5:12 Expected an operand but found else
            else{
```

But I need the parse tree as well with the error. Is there a way to do that using the nashorn

Comment: It is not a valid tree, you cannot parse it. The lexer expects to find the tokens that are defined in the language's rules. How do you expect the tree to look like when that } is missing?

Comment: What if the error is so fundamental ... that there isn't a parse tree?

Comment: If i did the same using the antlr4 it give an output  {
                                          "line": 5,
                                          "column": 12,
                                          "type": "CloseBrace",
                                          "text": "\u003cmissing \u0027}\u0027\u003e"
                                        }. this kind of thing inside parsetree. This is perfectlty ok